# Disable auto indention related to ":"

Tags: objective-c, vim, macvim

I program mostly in objective C using VIM.

When you break a command into multiple lines, VIM has a very annoying habit of trying to line up the ":" you put into the command. Now, a lot of programmers value this, I am not one of them. I would rather have tab indented commands than space indented ones (which is what happens with this type of auto indenting).

As an example:

```
[locationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"id" : @"locationID",
        @"name" : @"name",
        @"address" : @"address",
        @"city" : @"city",
        @"state" : @"state",
        @"zipcode" : @"zipcode",
        @"country" : @"country",
        }];
```

vs

```
[locationMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                             @"id" : @"locationID",
                                           @"name" : @"name",
                                        @"address" : @"address",
                                           @"city" : @"city",
                                          @"state" : @"state",
                                        @"zipcode" : @"zipcode",
                                        @"country" : @"country",
        }];
```

Is there any way to disable auto indention when typing ":"?

Comment: did you try checking https://github.com/b4winckler/vim-objc ??

Comment: Surely `:set noexpandtab` will prevent the spaces in indentation.

Comment: @Petesh: that plugin doesn't remove indention with ":", but attempts to solve cases where the ":" does weird things inside objective c.

Comment: @Petesh: I ended up taking the plugin you mentioned and modified it source to prevent any colon indenting.

Comment: For some reason, my own environment does not indent when using the colon - probably because I've been using it for so long that it's defaulting to a company I used to work for's C indentation standard

Answer (score 4):

The obj-c filetype appears to set up an `imap` for `:` to `*@<SNR>28_CompleteColon()`. You should be able to simply delete this in your own ftplugin.

Something like this should work:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/after/ftplugin
echo ':iunmap <buffer> :' > ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/objc_no_colon.vim
```

Comment: are those commands to be typed as is? After executing both commands, I still get indents based off of ":"

Comment: @ColdLogic: Yes they are. This is, of course, assuming that your vim has `~/.vim/after` in its `runtimepath`, but that's part of the default value for unix/OS X. What OS are you running on?

Comment: @ColdLogic: Oh that's really bizarre. I just checked and you're right, removing this mapping doesn't seem to have any effect on the alignment. I have no idea why not.

Comment: Yea, im on OS X, Lion to be more specific. Weird, I took the plugin that Petesh mentioned above and modified its source code to prevent any colon indenting.